# Applying unified color scale to tiles with gdal2tiles?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, tiles, color, gdal2tiles

**Background:**

I have a series of about 40 small GeoTIFFs that need to be merged together to make one large image. Each GeoTIFF has 2000 bands. I've tried using both `gdal_merge` and `gdal_retile` to pull the images together. This seems to work fine when I view it in QGIS or other tools.

**Problem:**

When I run gdal2tiles (`gdal2tiles.py --z 0-10 -w none GDD1.tif`)  it doesn't seem to recolor the images on the same scale (see image below). This may be an obvious question, but is there a way to tell GDAL to recolor the tiles based on a unified color scale?

[image: merged geotiff]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have this problem too.

Comment: no, I ended up (1) breaking each GeoTiff into its band, then (2) merging them together, then (3) coloring them and (4) creating the tiles.  Much more time consuming, but got a consistent issue.